# python wait queue and socket in single thread

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, queue, epoll

my app is a tcp server, using epoll to wait for requests.
i wanna wait for a queue in the same loop.
that is: **`wake up the thread either socket r/w is available or queue is not empty.`**

i surely googled a lot, but none good solution found.
i've thought about several ways to work around it:

1. set a timeout(e.g.0.5) for epoll.wait, and then queue.get_nowait until empty.
   in this way, cpu resource is wasted even if nothing to deal with.
   and it's not that real-time.
2. use domain socket instead of queue, so that epoll can wait for both.
   in this way, sender has to convert the python-object to string/binary data to
   transfer (and receiver versa), which is boring.

--- none of them satisfy me.

i wonder if epoll can wait for Event?
 --so that i can event.set() after queue.put().
or

Is there a good way to solve my problem?

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should look into non-blocking sockets.

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html#non-blocking-sockets

Comment: it's already non-blocking.... epoll.wait() will block but sockets won't. -- if you meaned 'make the epoll non-blocking', well that will cause dead-loop and high cpu